# Can't edit @FXML label after changing to different fxml file and then returning back

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

I have been stuck at editing a label's content for a few days now. I am making an app in which I load login.fxml at start and then change the fxml to for example admin_login.fxml  but then when I reload login.fxml again and try to set the text of Label using .setText then it gives me a null pointer Exception. 
Would really appreciate it if some one could help me with this problem.

Main.java

```
 public class Main extends Application {

Parent root;
FXMLLoader loader;

String login[][] = { {"admin"  ,"admin1234"  },
                     {"student","student1234"},
                     {"teacher","teacher1234"}  };

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    root = loader.load();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Practice Test Management System");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 700));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller.java

```
enter code here@FXML Button login_login_bn ;
@FXML TextField login_user_id;
@FXML TextField login_pass;
@FXML Label login_login_error;
@FXML Label login_connection_msg;
@FXML Button admin_set_bn;
@FXML Button admin_about_bn;
@FXML Button admin_users_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_students_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_subjects_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_tests_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_results_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_ques_bn;
@FXML Button teacher_about_bn;
@FXML Button student_about_bn;
@FXML Button student_tests_bn;
@FXML Button student_results_bn;
@FXML Button logout_bn;
@FXML Button login_condatabase_bn;
@FXML TextField super_user_id;
@FXML TextField super_pass;
@FXML Label super_msg_lb;
@FXML Button super_login_bn;
@FXML TextField login_db_name;
@FXML TextField login_db_user_id;
@FXML TextField login_db_pass;
@FXML Label login_db_connection_msg_lb;
@FXML Button login_db_connect_bn;

//Variables
Boolean adminlogin = false;
Boolean studentlogin = false;
Boolean teacherlogin = false;
//Classes
Admin admin = new Admin();
Main main = new Main();
CurrentUser currentuser = new CurrentUser();
DatabaseDriver databasedriver = new DatabaseDriver();

//Scenes
Scene login_scene;



public void dbConnected() throws IOException {
    currentuser.reset();
    Stage stage1;
    Parent root;
    stage1 = (Stage) login_db_connect_bn.getScene().getWindow();

    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 1000, 700);
    login_connection_msg.setText("database Connected"); //This isn't Working :(
    stage1.setScene(scene2);
    stage1.show();

}

public void superWindow() throws IOException{
    Stage stage1;
    stage1 = (Stage) login_condatabase_bn.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent root;
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("super_login.fxml"));
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root,400,400);
    stage1.setScene(scene2);
    stage1.show();
}
public void superLogin() throws IOException {
    if (admin.adminLogin(super_user_id.getText(),super_pass.getText())) {
        Stage stage1;
        Parent root;
        stage1 = (Stage) super_login_bn.getScene().getWindow();
        login_scene = (Scene) super_login_bn.getScene();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login_database_connect.fxml"));
        Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        stage1.setScene(scene2);
        stage1.show();
    } else {
        super_msg_lb.setText("Invalid User Id & Password");
    }
}
public void databaseConnect() throws IOException {
    Boolean connection ;
    connection = databasedriver.databaseConnection(login_db_name.getText(),login_db_user_id.getText(),login_db_pass.getText());
    if(connection){
        this.dbConnected();
    }else{
        System.out.println("connection false");
        login_db_connection_msg_lb.setText("Connection not successful....Try Again !");
    }
}
}
```

After loading login.fxml in start function in Main... It then executes superWindow() in controller then it executes superLogin() in controller ..then it runs databaseConnect() which then runs dbConnected but in dbConnected when I load login.fxml and edit Label login_connection_msg

`login_connection_msg.setText("database Connected");`

then it gives me a null pointer Exception :(

Comment: are you trying to use the same controller instance for multiple scenes? Does `login.fxml` contain the `login_connection_msg` `Node`?

Comment: sorry @fabian but i dont understand much about javafx nd my project is due this friday :( ..well what i did is load the login.fxml in start method then i click a button in it which runs the superWindow() that is it loads up the super_login.fxml ... in it i click a button which runs the superLogin() method which loads up the login_database_connect.fxml ..in this window i click a button which loads the login.fxml again by running dbConnected() method but if i try to edit the text in a label using setText then it throws a null exception, this is basically what i do ,hope this clarifies